# How to enable multiple select without showing all the options at once - Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, is it possible to enable multiple selection while still showing just a single line (as opposed to showing more than one options) before the user clicks on it?

I want users to be able to select more than one options, but I don't show the options to be shown before they even click on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can take a look at Chosen too : http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that built into Bootstrap. I recommend that you use an external plugin which looks like a single-line select but shows checkboxes when you click it. Example:

[image]

That screen cap is taken from this widget which seems to have the best reviews and is actively maintained:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 0):

See this [custom select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) for Bootstrap, the 3rd example.

[image]